# How to solve React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, firebase-authentication, react-hooks

How can I solve the **Line 31:6:  React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'fetchUserName' and 'history'. Either include them or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps** ? I am not able to solve it. I am using Firebase for authentication. Please help me!!!!!

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useAuthState } from "react-firebase-hooks/auth";
import { useHistory } from "react-router";
import "./Dashboard.css";
import { auth, db, logout } from "./firebase";

function Dashboard() {
  const [user, loading] = useAuthState(auth);
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const history = useHistory();

  const fetchUserName = async () => {
    try {
      const query = await db
        .collection("users")
        .where("uid", "==", user?.uid)
        .get();
      const data = await query.docs[0].data();
      setName(data.name);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
      alert("An error occured while fetching user data");
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (loading) return;
    if (!user) return history.replace("/");

    fetchUserName();
  }, [user, loading]);

  return (
    <div className="dashboard">
      <div className="dashboard__container">
        Logged in as
        <div>{name}</div>
        <div>{user?.email}</div>
        <button className="dashboard__btn" onClick={logout}>
          Logout
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Dashboard;
```

Comment: In your fetchUserName function you are making state changes to user name which is not included in you useEffect function dependencies. Add the name to your list of dependencies and that should resolve the warning.
also, I would recommend to read this <https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-it-safe-to-omit-functions-from-the-list-of-dependencies> to better understand best practices when it comes to useEffect

Answer (score 0):

Normally it should be fine to add 'fetchUserName' and 'history' to the array at the end of useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (loading) return;
  if (!user) return history.replace("/");

  fetchUserName();
}, [
  user, 
  loading,
  fetchUserName,
  history
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

React functional component uses closures. 
when state updates not all functions know the updated value, they only know the initialized value

when you are using `useEffect` you need to make sure that useEffect hook knows the updated values, even more, the functions that the useEffect invokes also need to know the updated values
so if you have a warning that says you missing some dependencies, you probably need to listen to it

If you really don't need it and you want to remove the warning you can put this **right before the end of the useEffect/ useCallback**

```
        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

But again they didn't send this by mistake, there are reasons why they send it and a good ones

Answer (score 0):

you could use this

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (loading) return;
    if (!user) return history.replace("/");

    fetchUserName();
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, [user, loading]);
```